# Error c4430 ? visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am new to creating and i try to use visual studio 2012

```
#include 
#include 

main()
{

    printf("MY NAME");

    getch();

}
```

Error   1   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\users\baya\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\baya_pj\baya_pj\source.cpp  5   1   Baya_PJ

Comment: Did you really not have complete includes? `#include` is not valid, it should be something like `#include <stdio.h>` etc... Also `main` needs a return type `int main()`.

Comment: You also need to specify a return type for main.  e.g. `int main()`

Comment: It is really not fair for people here to ask something like this instead of reading a book. c'mon man. It would have been a lot faster to just look up any C++ program.

Comment: Sorry Like this

#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

Comment: #include "stdio.h"
    int main() 
    { printf("my name"); return 0; }

Comment: The compiler should also have given you a line number. The line number would have pointed directly to the line that says `main()`. Did you try to understand the error message at all or to examine the code that the compiler complained about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code does not have proper includes, but it is not clear if that is the real code since you would have more errors then, but if it is then they should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

the other problem is that `main` needs a return type:

```
int main()
```

Comment: i'm sorry ): thank you so much!

Comment: @user2394984 Like named said this is pretty basic C++ and you should spend more time learning the basics before asking more questions on SO. Questions that do not show enough research will be down voted.